# Can We Use A 5.1 3a USB Type-C charger on a Raspberry Pi 4B 8 Gb or 400?

Tags: pi-4, power-supply

I am thinking of buying A Raspberry Pi 400 Only Keyboard ( not a kit). So for a power supply I don't want to buy the official power supply, But a adapter and a long cable ( such as [here](https://www.amazon.in/Lakshika-Charger-Adapter-Charging-Compatible/dp/B08GG6VMPW/ref=sr_1_5?crid=EWFDG3ZF528M&dchild=1&keywords=5v+3a+usb+c+adapter&qid=1610121547&sprefix=5v+3a+usb+c+%2Caps%2C282&sr=8-5) ). Can u just tell me if it will work, if not please suggest a power supply related to the official power supply but has a longer cable.

Thank You

Comment: Ideally you should avoid things sold as *chargers*.  The USB C ones are probably better than the USB 2.0/3.0 ones, but they potentially cannot handle the rapidly fluctuating current draw of an electronic device like the Pi (which is not a "low energy" mobile device, and does not have its own battery).

Answer (score 1):

> Q: "Can u just tell me if it will work"?

No - unfortunately we can't.

**Why?** *Because we don't know how long your ***"long cable"*** is, and we don't know what gauge wire is used.*

**What does "length & wire gauge" have to do with it?**

*The longer the wire, and the thinner the diameter, the higher the resistance - [as explained here](https://www.inchcalculator.com/wire-gauge-size-and-resistance-calculator/).*

*As the wire resistance increases, the voltage delivered to the RPi's USB input decreases. This is a consequence of [Ohm's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law). If the input voltage decreases below approx 4.6 Volts, the RPi will begin to "misbehave", and you will have problems with it.*

**What can be done?**

*There are several remedies, but they will require a non-standard method of power delivery to the RPi. There are other Q&A here on RPi SE that address some of those options; you may ask a new question if none of these address your situation.*

In the simplest terms: If you can tell us ***1. Length of cable***, and ***2. Gauge of wire used for power***, we can make a reasonable guess as to whether it will work. If you can't tell us that, then you will have to *buy-it-and-try-it*.

Comment: So can I use this official Raspberry Pi power supply as stated on Amazon [(here)](https://www.amazon.in/Raspberry-Pi-15-3W-USB-C-Supply/dp/B07XY8F3P7/ref=asc_df_B07XY8F3P7/?tag=googleshopdes-21&linkCode=df0&hvadid=397008884140&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=4395757154412404550&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9061943&hvtargid=pla-890727647647&psc=1&ext_vrnc=hi). This is how long I need the cable to be (approx -- 6-10feet).

Comment: @Dhruv-2676: What is it in my answer that you do not understand?

Comment: Everything That You Have Stated IS Not Understood By Me. Just Give Simple Answer Man! Don't Be Rude, If You Don't Want To Answer Please Don't!

Comment: @Dhruv-2676: AFAIK, English is the language we use here. If it's too difficult for you, maybe try somewhere else? Or - just wait... I'm sure all those who read your comments will be anxious to help you.